# TW6100W - Which frequency is used?

Tags: wireless-networking, projector

Does anyone know with which frequency the wireless transmitter that is delivered with my projector is emitting? The projector in question is EPSON TW6100W.

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: Doesn't say anything about that, just that the 3D-glasses is working on 2,4 GHz.

Comment: A call to Epson support may answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of devices usually communicates using Wi-Fi direct. Wi-Fi Direct products can work on 802.11 a, g and n Wi-Fi standards. All Wi-Fi Direct devices operate in the 2.4 GHz frequency band and can connect to 802.11g and some 802.11n devices. In addition, some Wi-Fi Direct devices work in the 5 GHz frequency band to connect to 802.11a and some 802.11n. Many devices operate in both frequency bands.